# Can I remove out-dated coloring from Apple Mail "Rules" settings?

Tags: mail.app

After experimentation with Apple Mail, Rules settings, I'm left with a rainbow-colored inbox, and **I want to remove all of that coloring which is no longer specified by my Rules settings.** I've tried using the "apply rules" command after selecting all messages, but all prior messages remain colored improperly.

**How can I do this?**

- I can't somehow "factory reset" Apple Mail, our tech guy will not be happy if the settings of the mail server, etc is messed up.
- I can't delete my message history, the old messages must be kept.

Comment: cross posting, was told Ask Different was better for my question than Super User. http://superuser.com/questions/928325/can-i-remove-out-dated-coloring-from-rules-in-apple-mail

Comment: It's preferable to request migration by flagging for a moderator than reposting.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The simples to way to do that for the OSX 10.7.5 - Mail 5.3

I believe it is done in Fonts.

[image: fonts]

Answer (score 0):

ios mail 10.3.
This worked for me:

select "format"
select "show colors"
select your desired color, probably black
click on the color box below

hope this helps